# Putting a file onto a linked list in java

Tags: java, file, list

I need help with putting strings from a file into a list (in Java).  Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class MyProgram7{
public static void main(String[] args){

    //Declare Variables
    File file = new File ("data7_names_Fall_2011.txt");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
    Prog7Methods pm = new Prog7Methods();

    MyList<String> list = new MyArrayList<String>();
  }
}
```

I want to put each name in the list, so that I can append and insert and such.  Here is my file:

Lee Keith Austin Kacie Jason Sherri     Jordan     Corey Reginald Brian Taray 
Christopher Randy Henry Jeremy Robert    Joshua   Robert   Eileen 
Cassandra Albert Russell   Ethan   Cameron Tyler Alex Kentrell  rederic

I know I probably need to use a for loop but I just cannot figure out a way to go about this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
...
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
// add to list
while (input.hasNext()) {
    list.add(input.next());
}
// display
for (String s : list) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: This seems like it would make sense. I am getting this error:  MyProgram7.java:14: unreported exception java.io.FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
  Scanner input = new Scanner(file);

Comment: @Josh: Either wrap your calls with try ..catch(FileNotFoundException ex) or use throws FileNotFoundException clause

Comment: Thanks you.  I am also getting this error:  MyProgram7.java:22: foreach not applicable to expression type
  for (String s : list){

Comment: I also need for each name to be in a different node.

Comment: @Josh: what is the type of your List? is it `Iteratable`?

Comment: it is <E>. I forget what it is called but it can be any type.  I am just using strings.  I got the list to print but I just need each name in a separate node.

Comment: @Josh: separate node! what is the type of the list? Choose the right implementation based on your need. In my example, the list is an ArrayList

Comment: @Josh: then the `add` call would append the string at the end of the list(yes. in the separate node).